# Rewrite url with querystring

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am creating a new website for a company and I am creating new url's for all pages. For example a forum topic used to be `/cont/forum/showTopic.php?id=5` and  now it is `/forum/5`.

This site has a lot of backlinks from all over the web and I would like to make sure that these links still got to the correct page. I have already tried several things with `.htaccess`, but I am stuck with getting the value of the querystring.

If someone could help me with this example. Once I know how it is done, I can do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `/cont/forum/showTopic.php?id=5` to `/forum/5`

Place this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+cont/forum/showTopic\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forum/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: It should be `301` now. It is always good idea to keep `302` while testing the rules (to avoid browser caching issues) and change that to `301` eventually.